# How virtual views are not stored on database

Tags: sql, database, oracle, view

AS we know major difference between view and materialized view is- views are not stored on database and materialized views are stored physically on database. 
But it will give output in below example.

e.g I have base table emp having 5 fields and I created v_emp view based on this table with only 3 required fields. and I run below query it gives correct output

```
desc v_emp;
```

My question is: if views are not stored anywhere on database from where it fetches data.

Note: I am using Oracle database

Comment: View definitions are stored in the database alright. When you select from an unmaterialized view, you basically run the query which is stored in the view definition.

Comment: View definitions are stored in the database, but they are not a data storage structure. A view is simply a saved select statement that is executed when you query the view.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, `view` is nothing but stored/saved query. So it's doesn't store any data and every time you run the view saying `select * from v_emp` behind the scene it run the underline `select` query saying `select fld1, fld2, fld3 from employee;`

Answer (score 1):

Views ARE stored in the database. There are two main components of a view:

1) The definitions of the view... as in the select statement(for both types of views).

2) The physical storage of actual rows in the database (materialized views only).